# a combinations/counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Six volleyball teams, each of which consists of three men and three women, are competing in a tournament.  A reporter wants to interview one person from each team, being sure to have three men and three women total.  How many ways can the six people to be interviewed be chosen?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by choosing the teams for male interviewees. This can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways, which fixes the female teams. Then we select one male from each of the three teams, giving us $\binom{3}{1} = 3$ options per team. By rule of product, we multiply: $\binom{6}{3} \cdot 3^{3}$, which gives us the count of men. Since the female teams are fixed, there are $\binom{3}{1} = 3$ ways to choose a woman from a given team. So there are $3^{3}$ ways to choose the women. By rule of product we multiply: $\binom{6}{3} \cdot 3^{6}$ as our final count.

Answer (score 0):

The reporter needs three men and three women, so there are $$\frac{6!}{3!3!}=20$$ ways to determine which teams get either male or female representation (essentially reordering the sequence of letters "MMMFFF"). Then, there are $3^6$ ways to pick a person of the designated gender from the team. So, there are $$20\times3^6=14580\text{ ways}.$$

Comment: It's three ways per team. The selection of a person on a given team is independent of the persons on the other team. So you have men $M_{11}, M_{12}, M_{13}, M_{21}, M_{22}, M_{23}, M_{31}, M_{32}, M_{33}$. You pick one man from $M_{1i}$, one from $M_{2j}$ and one from $M_{3k}$, where $i, j, k \in \{0, 1, 2\}$. Thus, there are $27$ total options for selecting the men, not $3$. (I didn't downvote, but just wanted to point out what it should be). :-)

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. That should be $3^6$, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different tack.

There are 6 interview slots.  There are 18 men to choose from for the first slot, 15 for the second and 12 for the third. The choices decline by 3 because once a man is chosen for the interview, his two male team mates are excluded from the pool of male interviewees.

The same sequence applies to the three women, i.e., 18,15 and 12.

The product of 18*15*12*18*15*12 gives the number of ways you could choose the interviewees if the order in which they were interviewed mattered. It doesn't so you divide the product by 6! which is the number of ways to arrange 6 distinct interviewees.

That works out to 14580.